# CPU usage as a percentage for the whole system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, cpu-usage, ram

I'm trying to make a botinfo command with resource usage stats. I've got memory covered (although percentage for memory usage would be nice too) but I can't seem to get cpu usage. I've tried multiple packages and methods, none worked. My memory thing is:

```
const usedMemory = os.totalmem() - os.freemem()
```

How would I make cpu usage and return it in an discord.js embed?

Comment: if not using something like exec to call `grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}'` to get % your need a ticker, then you average it then * 100, you might be interested in using a lib like https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation they have this in [currentLoad](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation#8-current-load-processes--services) which if you look at the code your see how it collects the metrics, using an aforementioned ticker

Comment: It says Promise: <pending> in the console when I try to console.log it. And it says [object Promise] in the discord.js embed

Comment: most things return promises in js, you just need to know how to handle them, all shown in the docs in the links above, read them or you could google Promise: <pending> your find a bunch of learning resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. There's a function in node-os-utils (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-os-utils) called loadavgTime that needs to be used with loadavg-windows (https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadavg-windows) if you're on windows. It takes the os.loadavg from the last minute by default. I then divided it by 2 and then multiplied by 10 cos for some reason it outputs a weird number (between 1.__ and 2.__). It gives it as a percentage, you just need to add the % after it when console.log ing it. Here's the code:

```
const osu = require('node-os-utils')
require('loadavg-windows')

const cpu = osu.cpu
const usage = (cpu.loadavgTime() / 2) * 10

console.log(usage)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `process.cpuUsage()` method returns the user and system CPU time usage of the current process, in an object with properties user and system, whose values are `microsecond values` (millionth of a second). These values measure time spent in `user` and `system` code respectively, and may end up being greater than actual elapsed time if multiple CPU cores are performing work for this process.

The result of a previous call to process.cpuUsage() can be passed as the argument to the function, to get a diff reading.

```
import { cpuUsage } from 'process';

const startUsage = cpuUsage();
// { user: 38579, system: 6986 }

// spin the CPU for 500 milliseconds
const now = Date.now();
while (Date.now() - now < 500);

console.log(cpuUsage(startUsage));
// { user: 514883, system: 11226 }
```

For more details check [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cpuusage_previousvalue).

If you want to get in %, you can use existing npm module: [node-os-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-os-utils). You can use it like this:

```
const osu = require('node-os-utils')
const cpu = osu.cpu

const count = cpu.count() // 8

cpu.usage()
  .then(cpuPercentage => {
    console.log(cpuPercentage) // 10.38
  })

const osCmd = osu.osCmd

osCmd.whoami()
  .then(userName => {
    console.log(userName) // admin
  })
```

For more details, check the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-os-utils).

Comment: How do I get the cpu usage for the whole system and return it in a discord.js embed as a percentage though?

Comment: I have updated the answer, this might help to get exactly what you need. % can be calculated by this module. If you are able to get the memory and passing it to discord, you need to do the same with this.

Comment: It returns [object Promise] but correctly displays it in the console

Comment: I also tried making a variable and making it equal 100  - cpu.free() but it says nan

Comment: Can you share the code where you want to use it? You just need to understand how to get the promise values- there are two methods - then/catch or async/await.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a way to do it. There's a function in the package called loadavgTime that needs to be used with loadavg-windows. It takes the os.loadavg from the last minute by default. I then divided it by 2 and then multiplied by 10 cos for some reason it outputs a weird number (between 1.__ and 2.__)